# How do I auto scale down a font in a Text widget to fit the max number of lines?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to use `BoxFit.scaleDown` in a `FittedBox`'s fit property to scale the font down in a `Text` widget to accommodate strings of varying length.

However, the below code will scale down the entire string and make it fit on one line, For the below example, I would like the font scaled down so that the string can fit on two lines (per `maxLines` property of the `Text` widget).

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Multi-Line Label Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Multi-Line Label Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textStyle = const TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0);
    final text =
        'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting'
        'industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text'
        'ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type'
        'and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.';
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              child: new Text(
                text,
                maxLines: 2,
                style: textStyle,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where would you like the line break?

Comment: I think anywhere is fine so long as the text expands to use the max number of lines.

Comment: is maxLines working for you? It always shows in single line with fitted box

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can use the auto text package

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/auto_size_text

after install it, just replace all of 'Text' to 'AutoSizeText' and you will find every things will be good :)

Comment: I agree that AutoSizeText is the best answer, but it's definitely not as simple as "replace all of 'Text' to 'AutoSizeText' ". You need to choose your ideal font size in the TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0), then using the AutoSizeText, you need to use the "minFontSize:" to choose how small the text CAN go, then use "maxLines:" to determine the amount of overflow your text is allowed. There are obviously more features provided by the package site, but I feel that this answer should at least provide an example.

Comment: Solution without Plugin- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67651675/7857541

Comment: @Yash that solution actually uses this plugin

Answer (score 41):

An easy drop-in solution is to use `FittedBox` with `fit: BoxFit.scaleDown`:

```dart
Container(
  width: 100.0,
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
    // Optionally apply `alignment` to position the text inside the box:
    //alignment: Alignment.topRight,
    child: SizedBox(
      child: Text('\$1,299.99'),
  )
)
```

Comment: This is not working with multiline text. It's showing the text exactly as same as the screenshot attached with this question.

Answer (score 10):

We got 2 ready-to-use solutions to this depending on the constraints you want to have.

### 1. Scale only

This solution works if you like how the layout looks on some reference screen size, want to treat the text area as a box and just scale up or down the entire box given other sized screens.

Take a reference screen. Lay everything out as intended. Find out the size of the box containing the text (by showing the render tree by pressing 't' during debug for instance). Then wrap the text containing box with a [`SizedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) of the same size as measured. Then wrap that with your [`FittedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html).

The restriction is basically that your text is laid out exactly the same way on all screens and you'll have the same aspect ratio for the text box.

### 2. Multiple references

Given a parent with variable size, first use a [`LayoutBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to get the parent's size during runtime, and then manually adjust the font size in the child text widget to make sure it fits.

The text layout is more fluid and the containing box can have different aspect ratios, but you'd have to check on as many screens sizes as the font size switches you have. Though it's easy to make sure that the text doesn't overflow at any screen size using [widget tests](https://flutter.io/testing/#widget-testing)

---

We can also create more complex but automatic means if there are more concrete examples of generalized use cases involving dependent font scaling

Comment: It seems like using a SizedBox means that there is no way to remove the extraneous space within the box if the text is short (e.g. 3 characters instead of two lines worth). E.g. if I want to use only as many lines as necessary to render the text.

Answer (score 4):

This happened in my app:

[image: This is with a long title]
[image: This is the long title in the horizontal mode]

I solved by calculating the maximum number of chars shown in one line and  reducing dynamically the Text FontSize if its string length is greater.

### **Get the char width of your text**

First of all, I calculated the width of every char shown.
For doing that I needed the effective container width and the number of chars shown.
To get the screen width (that actually is the container width), I put my Text widget inside a `LayoutBuilder`:

```
new LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
   //screen width got from the LayoutBuilder
   double maxWidth = constraint.biggest.width;

   //I'm going to change this dinamically
   double fontSize = 33.0;

   //return my widget
   return new Text(
        _brand.name,
        maxLines: 1,
        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize),
    );
}
```

To get the chars shown before a new line, I put a big string in the Text and I manually counted how many chars were shown in one line. I put this value in a const (`maxCharInOneLine`) and then I was able to calculate the single char width: I divided the maximum witdh by `maxCharInOneLine`:

```
new LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
   //screen width got from the LayoutBuilder
   double maxWidth = constraint.biggest.width;

   //chars shown manually counted
   const int maxCharInOneLine = 17;
   
   //single char width
   int charWidth = (maxWidth / maxCharInOneLine).toInt();
   
   //TO RUN IN DEBUG MODE
   print("Char size with this screen and Text's TextStyle: " + charWidth.toString());
   ...
}
```

I runned the code above in the debug mode in order to get the `charSize` value, then I put is in a const and I removed that code that is useless at runtime.

### **Change dynamically the font**

Now, with a constant char width and a variable container width (got from the `LayoutBuilder`) you can have every time the maximum number of chars that fits in one line.

```
new LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
    const int charWidth=16;
    //screen width got from the LayoutBuilder
    double maxWidth = constraint.biggest.width;

    //dinamically get the char number that fits in one line with this screen
    int charsPerLine = (maxWidth / charWidth).toInt();

    //if it doesn't fit in a line, reduce the fontSize
    double fontSize = (_brand.name.length <= charsPerLine) ? 33.0 : 23.0;

    return new Text(
        _brand.name,
        maxLines: 1,
        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize),
    );
}
```

The result:

[image: The text is dynamically reduced]
[image: The long title in the horizontal mode has the same size]

My solution is not the best, but it works well in my case.

I'd like to get feedbacks. :)

EDIT Aug 2020: You can now simply use the library [AutoSizeText](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your `Text` inside a `FittedBox` widget without setting any `fit` value.

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 10,
  child: FittedBox(
    child: Text('Your Text'),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -3):

Did you try using the Flexible widget

```
new Flexible(
  child: new Text(
    text,
    style: textStyle,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  ),
),
```