# How to dynamically resize text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I retrieve a piece of text from an API. I want to allot a set amount of space to it (say a max Container with width: 300.0 and height: 100.0). Sometimes, the piece of text fits in this Container with font size 30.0. In other times, it won't fit unless I set the text size to 24.0.

Is there a way to dynamically resize text based on its parent container space?

I've built a Container with a ConstrainedBox, which lets me define the max size of the text space. I've also wrapped my Text with a LayoutBuilder. I was hoping that I could check the height of the space of the text, and based on that, determine how to size the text. Like this:

```
    Container(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: 300.0,
          maxWidth: 300.0,
          minHeight: 30.0,
          maxHeight: 100.0,
        ),
        child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          if (/* height is larger than 100.0? height is over the constraints? */) { return textWithSize24(); }
          return textWithSize30();
        }),
      ),
    ),
```

How can I determine the "height that the text would take up if it were size 30.0"?
Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way and I'm supposed to use `maxLines` to determine this instead? But how do we know that we've reached more than `maxLines`?

The other way to do it is to use the number of characters in my String to determine when to change font sizes. This seems kind of manual.

Comment: scaleDown may be useful - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665083/how-do-i-auto-scale-down-a-font-in-a-text-widget-to-fit-the-max-number-of-lines

Answer (score 371):

You can use [`FittedBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) to manage text based on height or width.

**For Ex.**

Simply just wrap your `Text` widget to `FittedBox` widget like, Here I want to resize my AppBar text based on width.

```dart
AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, 
        child: Text('Hey this is my long text appbar title')
    ),
),
```

Text will be resized based on width of AppBar.

Comment: Works fine in iOS emulator but not on my real device. The width becomes the width of the screen not the surrounding widget.

Comment: Sorry I checked in both iOS and Android device and working well. If you still facing same then ask question with relevant code. We can identify where exact issue come.

Comment: @iPatel can i implement with TextFiled widget?

Comment: I find my text is forced to fill the box. Is there a way of constraining a max font size with this method?

Comment: @louisdeb I faced the same issue, use https://github.com/leisim/auto_size_text instead. More flexible

Comment: Also, by using FittedBox your text won't break anymore.

Comment: @louisdeb I have an easy solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63124491/12661107 You can constrain the text size like this using  BoxFit.scaleDown .

Comment: It's the best solution I have found so far, but I reverted to using a TextOverflow instead. The FittedBox does not allow to define a minimal font size and the test can become ridiculously small.

Comment: Does not work for me, FittedBox does not resize my text

Comment: Could you share your code where you get stuck and what your requirement because this works for all of us.. *(Need to see your requirement because sometime it happens )*

Comment: auto_size_text doesn't work with selectable text on the web.

Comment: I am trying to use it with a TextField() but for some reason FittedBox() is causing "RenderBox is not laid out". Maybe someone can tell me why, i even asked a question on that.

Comment: Same issue of @iocomxda - this works beautifully almost everywhere, except `TextFields`. Has anyone found a good solution for this? Even better if it does not require more packages.

Answer (score 135):

Using a `FittedBox` with  `BoxFit.scaleDown`  and fixing the `FontSize` you can adjust the maximum size of the font.

If the content is small, it occupies the minimum width with the specified font size. At the same time, if the content is large, it resizes to the smallest font size.

```
FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
    child: Text(
        "Text here",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
    ),
)
```

If you need the text to fill the entire width, using any font size, use `BoxFit.cover`:

```
FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    child: Text(
        "Text here",
        //style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
    ),
)
```

Comment: Hey, this one works really well with a single line text box. What should I do if I want a Text widget which I want to span multiple line?

Answer (score 68):

You can do it using the [auto_size_text](https://github.com/leisim/auto_size_text) package:

```
Container(
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      minWidth: 300.0,
      maxWidth: 300.0,
      minHeight: 30.0,
      maxHeight: 100.0,
    ),
    child: AutoSizeText(
      "yourText",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
    ),
  ),
);
```

You can also set `maxLines` to constrain the text even further or use `presetFontSizes` if you only want to allow specific font sizes.

Comment: Awesome plugin! Thank you :)

Comment: this one is more flexible than FittedBox

Comment: this package is good. But facing this issue: cut in the resulting string
https://github.com/leisim/auto_size_text/issues/64

Comment: NOO. don't use it. it has alot of bugs. use FittedBox instead

Comment: It also doesn't support selectable text afaik. Use FittedBox with BoxFit.scaleDown if possible.

Comment: This plugin is awesome. Also fixed RenderLayout Issues

Comment: unfortunately this plugin sucks, a lot of bugs, impossible to use it

Comment: @GustavoBordin you don't know to use it that's why. I also thought it isn't working but you have to set a width and height so it knows how to scale down or up

Comment: @SwiftiSwift is right! The plugins seem to be buggy if don't know how to use it. It expects constraints at least the width, and if you want to use it in a Column, wrap it inside Expanded or anything that constrains the height otherwise, it will overflow

Answer (score 20):

FittedBox worked in my case with multiple lines.

```
SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              child: Text(
                widget.model.poem,
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 13):

I used it this way and it worked perfectly:

```
Flexible(
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    child: AutoSizeText(
      'your specific text',
      maxLines: 1,
      style: TextStyle(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

This gives us **flexibility** and ensures that our child widget is inside and behaving as expected (**containing**), in addition to using **[auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)**.

Comment: BIGG KISSES TO YOU <33333

Comment: `Flexible`, `FittedBox` and `Text` widgets together work just fine.

Answer (score 11):

**Responsive_Flutter**, I had the same issues since reading your problem. I found it **Works every time** using this package to resize your fonts.

This Flutter package is for scaling the size your apps UI and `fontSize` across different sized devices. (The example shows the top text using the Responsive_Flutter package and the bottom text without plugin.

https://github.com/layounisl/responsive_flutter

**You can install in 30 seconds - 3 Steps**

1. Add dependencies to yaml file `responsive_flutter: ^0.0.4`
2. `import 'package:responsive_flutter/responsive_flutter.dart';`
3. `child: Text("Responsive flutter", style: TextStyle(fontSize: ResponsiveFlutter.of(context).fontSize(3)),`

[image: App using Flutter]

Comment: Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:responsive_flutter

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety

Comment: This package no longer works for Flutter with Null Safety.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a list of things I tried which may work for you depending on your use case: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18431

Ultimately I went with a function that sets the font size based on the length of the String (i.e. with if-else statements).

Answer (score 5):

I found A solution to shrink down the text with a max font size without using the plugin:

```
Expanded(
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
    child: Text('${widget.article.price * chosenQuantity} DH',
      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25 , fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Normal state :
[normal text with 25 in fontSize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsS8s.png)

And if the Text is larger :
[the text shrinks as there is no more space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9B0G.png)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing I found was `auto_size_text: ^2.1.0`.  As simple as importing the dependency and using `AutoSizeText()` instead of `Text()`

```
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 200.0,
            height: 140.0,
            child: AutoSizeText(
              'This string will be automatically resized to fit in two lines.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
              maxLines: 2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: autosizetext has a lot of bugs

Answer (score 1):

Just generate the font size according to the text length and the maximum rendering area. `300.0 * 100.0` in your case, without forgetting the areas lost during the rendering of the text.

like this :

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StateMyWidget createState() => _StateMyWidget();
}

class _StateMyWidget extends State<MyWidget> {
  static const _QUOTES = [
    {"quote": "mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm", "author": "test"},
    {"quote": "Talk is cheap. Show me the code.", "author": "Linus Torvalds"},
    {"quote": "First, solve the problem. Then, write the code.", "author": "John Johnson"},
    {"quote": "To iterate is human, to recurse divine.", "author": "L. Peter Deutsch"},
    {"quote": "The best thing about a boolean is even if you are wrong, you are only off by a bit.", "author": "Anonymous"},
    {"quote": "Software is like sex: It’s better when it’s free.", "author": "Linus Torvalds"},
    {"quote": "The first 90% of the code accounts for the first 90% of the development time.  The remaining 10% of the code accounts for the other 90% of the development time.", "author": "Tom Cargill"},
    {"quote": "I think that it’s extraordinarily important that we in computer science keep fun in computing. When it started out it was an awful lot of fun. Of course the paying customers got shafted every now and then and after a while we began to take their complaints seriously. We began to feel as if we really were responsible for the successful error-free perfect use of these machines. I don’t think we are. I think we’re responsible for stretching them setting them off in new directions and keeping fun in the house. I hope the ﬁeld of computer science never loses its sense of fun. Above all I hope we don’t become missionaries. Don’t feel as if you’re Bible sales-men. The world has too many of those already. What you know about computing other people will learn. Don’t feel as if the key to successful computing is only in your hands. What’s in your hands I think and hope is intelligence: the ability to see the machine as more than when you were ﬁrst led up to it that you can make it more.", "author": "Alan J. Perlis"},
    {"quote":"Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live","author": "John Woods"},
    {"quote":"You've baked a really lovely cake, but then you've used dog shit for frosting.","author": "Steve Jobs"},
    {"quote": "Most software today is very much like an Egyptian pyramid with millions of bricks piled on top of each other, with no structural integrity, but just done by brute force and thousands of slaves.","author": "Alan Kay" },
    {"quote": "Software suppliers are trying to make their software packages more ‘user-friendly’…  Their best approach so far has been to take all the old brochures and stamp the words ‘user-friendly’ on the cover.","author": "Bill Gates"},
  ];

  static const AREA_LOST_PERCENT = 5;

  final rand = math.Random();

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (timeVal) {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Map<String, String> mapQuote = _QUOTES[rand.nextInt(_QUOTES.length)];

    final authorW =
        Text(mapQuote["author"], style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic));

    final quoteW = Text(
      mapQuote["quote"],
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: autoSize(
          quoteLength: mapQuote["quote"].length,
          parentArea: (350 - 10 * 2 - 16 * 2) * (450 - 10 * 2),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final containerW0 = Container(
        height: 450.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Center(child: quoteW));

    final containerW1 = Container(
        height: 500.0,
        width: 350,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        color: Colors.purple,
        child: Column(children: [authorW, containerW0]));

    return containerW1;
  }

  double autoSize({@required int quoteLength, @required int parentArea}) {
    assert(quoteLength != null, "`quoteLength` may not be null");
    assert(parentArea != null, "`parentArea` may not be null");
    final areaOfLetter = parentArea / quoteLength;
    final pixelOfLetter = math.sqrt(areaOfLetter);
    final pixelOfLetterP = pixelOfLetter - (pixelOfLetter * AREA_LOST_PERCENT) / 100;
    return pixelOfLetterP;
  }
}
```

the escape characters must be taken into account during the allocation of the percentage of lost areas. it is best to remove them if the variation is excessive.

[Online view -> dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/06b25e04d602c6534a23d679cc81055d)

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to do this.

1. Using FittedBox
2. Using TextPainter (calculate width with text Painter
   and update font )

https://prafullkumar77.medium.com/how-to-dynamically-resize-text-in-flutter-bca80415a4d2

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to surround `FittedBox` with `Flexible`. as bellow example.

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Flexible(
        child: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          child: Text(
              "${(matrix.duration! / 60).toStringAsFixed(0)} min. ",
              style: textStyle(context)),
        ),
      ),
      dot(context),
      Flexible(
        child: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          child: Text(
              "${(matrix.distance! / 1000).toStringAsFixed(1)} km",
              style: textStyle(context)),
        ),
      )
    ]),
```

Both `fit:BoxFit.fitWith` and `fit:BoxFit.scaleDown` worked and have same experience.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and wrote my own package, as my requirements where slightly different from the already known packages.

- Scales font size of automatically.
- But also accessing the font size calculation programmatically.
- Hyphenation for various languages.
- Binary search instead of linear search for best font size.

Status is "works for me", really wrote that primarily for my use case.

Package:

https://pub.dev/packages/text_wrap_auto_size

Demo:

https://xerik.github.io/text_wrap_auto_size/#/

```dart
final style = TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
    color: Colors.red,
    fontFamiliy: 'Courier',  
    // ...
);

final text = Text(
    'text',
    style: style,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    // ...
);

TextWrapAutoSize(text);

// Or with automatic hyphenation:

TextWrapAutoSizeHyphend(text,'en_us');
```

```dart
Solution sol = TextWrapAutoSize.solution(
    Size size, Text text);

// Or with automatic hyphenation:

Solution sol = TextWrapAutoSizeHyphend.solution(
    Size size, Text text, 'en_us');

print(sol.textString); // String for easy reference

print(sol.style); // TextStyle with Font Size and all other attrs.

print(sol.sizeInner); // Size of Text Box

print(sol.sizeOuter); // Size of Outer Box

SizedBox(
    width: sol.sizeOuter.width,
    height: sol.sizeOuter.height,
    child: Text(sol.textString, style: sol.style),
);
```

Language code for hyphenation:

```dart
[af, as, bg, bn, ca, cop, cs, cy, da, de_1901, de_1996, de_ch_1901, el_monoton, el_polyton, en_gb, en_us, eo, es, et, eu, fi, fr, fur, ga, gl, grc, gu, hi, hr, hsb, hu, hy, ia, id, is, it, ka, kmr, kn, la_x_classic, la, lt, lv, ml, mn_cyrl_x_lmc, mn_cyrl, mr, mul_ethi, nb, nl, nn, or, pa, pl, pms, pt, rm, ro, ru, sa, sh_cyrl, sk, sl, sv, ta, te, th, tk, tr, uk, zh_latn_pinyin]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `textScaleFactor` attribute in the `MediaQueryData` class to limit how big a text get

Comment: The text scaling factor attribute allows you, as its name suggests, to scale the font size, not to constrain it!

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Instead constraining my text between a min and a max, I was looking for a way to keep my FontSize relative to the width of the parent. With the textScaleFactor and the LayoutBuilder I was able to achieve this behavior.