# how to make flutter app font responsive for tablet?

Tags: flutter, responsive

> **flutter app need to make responsive for tablet , how to write if
> ---------------------- size condition can u help me **

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: _onWillPop,
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Constant.BLACK_COLOR,
            appBar: AppBar(
              centerTitle: true,


    ******this is my example code , i need to make bigger font only in tablet ******
```

**i tried sizer but not working  i m a fresher , help me if u know**

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751226/how-to-dynamically-resize-text-in-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) package

```
   Text(
     '16sp, will not change with the system.',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 16.sp, // this will make font responsive
      ),
    ),
```

Or you can identify device type with below code

```
  static bool isMobile(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 650;

  static bool isTablet(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 1100 &&
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 650;

  static bool isDesktop(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the [auto_size_text](https://github.com/leisim/auto_size_text) package:

```
Container(
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    ),
    child: AutoSizeText(
      "yourText",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
    ),
  ),
);
```

You can change the constaints accordingly and this will overall make your app more responsive.