# How to calculate fontsize of same height by component height?

Tags: flutter, fonts, flame

There's a `RectComponent`, and a `TextComponent` inside. The text will change length sometimes.

So I need "text adaptation".

[image]

The fontsize :

```
The size of glyphs (in logical pixels) to use when painting the text.
```

I cannot find the conversion method between fontSize(logical pixels) and component size.

Is there some formula between "component size" and "font size"?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to automatically fit the text in the size of the `RectangleComponent`.
You can however use `TextComponent.textRenderer.measureWidth` and calculate whether the font size has to be smaller or larger than it currently is.

Remember that if you don't use a mono-spaced font, a string with the same amount of characters as another string might become different widths.

Answer (score -1):

You can use FittedBox, check this answer out:
[How to dynamically resize text in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751226/how-to-dynamically-resize-text-in-flutter)

So, basically, FittedBox makes sure the content always stays within an area.

Comment: FittedBox is not in Flame