# Flutter: How to Auto-Fit Text Inside (Expanded) Floating Action Button?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, responsive-design, floating-action-button

Let's say in Flutter you have:

```
return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(myObject.unknownUntilRunTimeText),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(myObject.unknownUntilRunTimeText),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

How do you make sure that text auto-fits (shrinks, presumably) to fit the button?

I tried to use FittedBox, but what it appears is happening in this case is that the FABS effective width is larger than the FAB (due to the expansion in a row, presumably)... and so even if you resize the text, it is still too large:

[image]

The vertical scribbles indicate where I assume Flutter is considering where the edges are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically resize text in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751226/how-to-dynamically-resize-text-in-flutter)

Comment: unfortunately not.  I've editted the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FittedBox`.
**Example**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed:(){},
          child: FittedBox(
            child: Text("Your text")
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Hey. Please don't answer duplicates as  I already flagged this question as a duplicate in the comments

Comment: sorry if my answer upsets you, when I posted this answer I didn't see your comment.

Comment: not a problem..

Comment: Appreciate it, I editted the original question as it was too general before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FloatingActionButtom.extended()`

Comment: Care to elaborate?