# how to set font size dynamically according to device height and width without use any package

Tags: flutter

I want to give size in flutter according to device size which size given in Figma I saw many solution but not too perfect for example I give size 65 to text then it use for all devices

```
Text(
'Find your\nGadget',
      style:  TextStyle(
      fontSize:  65,
      color: AppColors.splashTextColor,
      fontFamily: AppFonts.raleWayExtraBold
))
```

Comment: Just use mediaquery width in your fontsize and you are all set to go. You do not need any packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically resize text in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751226/how-to-dynamically-resize-text-in-flutter)

Comment: You should never change font size based on device size.  Font size (and everything else) is measured in display pixels, which do not change based on the display size or resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `ThemeData` is from material
In `ThemeData` you can use

```
    static final ThemeData appTheme = ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        textTheme: textTheme, 
       ........
 1. you have to set `textTheme` 

         static final TextTheme textTheme = TextTheme(
            headline1: _headline1,
            headline2: _headline2,
            headline3: _headline3,
            subtitle1: _subtitle1,
            subtitle2: _subtitle2,
            bodyText1: _bodyText1,
            bodyText2: _bodyText2,
            caption: _caption,
            button: _buttonText,
          );
    
     static final TextStyle _headline1 = const TextStyle(
        color: black,
        letterSpacing: 0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      ).comfortaa();
    
      static final TextStyle _headline2 = const TextStyle(
        color: black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      ).comfortaa();
    
      static final TextStyle _headline3 = const TextStyle(
        color: black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      ).comfortaa();
    
      static final TextStyle _subtitle1 = const TextStyle(
        color: black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      ).comfortaa();
    
      static final TextStyle _subtitle2 = const TextStyle(
        color: black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      ).comfortaa();
    
    
      static final TextStyle _bodyText1 = const TextStyle(
        color: black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      ).nunito();
    
      static final TextStyle _bodyText2 = const TextStyle(
        color: black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      ).nunito();
    
      static final TextStyle _caption = const TextStyle(
        color: black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      ).nunito();
```

---

*> Note :comforta and nunito is my fontfamily*

---

For usecase

```
Text( "hello",
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FittedBox` for this:

```
FittedBox(
fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
child: 
  Text(
    "Text here",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
  )
)
```

Try using `BoxFit.scaleDown` or `BoxFit.cover` for different variations

Comment: if i use fitted box without parent then is work? i mean use in row and column

Comment: Yes you can use it directly without any issues and if some issue arises just wrap this inside a `Container`

Comment: i am use this approach Text('Full description',style: TextStyle(fontSize: constraints.maxHeight * 0.0358),), is ok or not?

Comment: You can use it but I wouldn't recommend as you should use `Mediaquery aspectRatio` cause text is impacted by height and width both which is why I was insisting on using `FittedBox`

Comment: you mean aspectRation  *  0.25 like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size` to get the device size.

and then get device data like width or whatever you want:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, 

MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, MediaQuery.of(context).size.aspectRatio
```

For example, I use this method to handle padding, I use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` to determine padding of general elements

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your text widget with SizedBox which will handle the height/width dynamically and FittedBox which will fit the size of the Text child according to FittedBox's parent (i.e. SizedBox):

```
SizedBox( //Preferred to use either width or height according to your requirements
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02 //(2% of screen height)
  child: FittedBox(
    child: Text(
        'Find your\nGadget',
              style:  TextStyle(
              //fontSize:  65,
              color: AppColors.splashTextColor,
              fontFamily: AppFonts.raleWayExtraBold
        )
     )
  }
}
```