# How to achieve relative font sizing in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

how do I achieve relative font sizing in flutter? i.e, A font size of 16.0 might be proper in a Iphone X emulator but overflows in a Iphone 5s as the font size is huge for the 5s screen.Please feel free to tag anybody who might be able to help me.
[outlook from IphoneX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GlU6.png)
[outlook from Iphone 5s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBmlW.png)

Comment: You've seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665083/how-do-i-auto-scale-down-a-font-in-a-text-widget-to-fit-the-max-number-of-lines

Comment: @Rexford That is unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FittedBox to achieve this:

```
FittedBox(fit:BoxFit.cover, child: Text("Hello World"))
```