# How to shrink and expand a Wrap widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to shrink and expand my Wrap widget when the size of the parent Container is increased or decreased.  The fonts of the individual children should increase or decrease along with the size of the boxes.  What is the best way to achieve this?

I have tried FittedBox (scaledDown) which reduces the sizes but then widget doesn't wrap at all (!) and all the children remain on one line.

This is the default behavious (if the Wrap widget is defined in a Container with a specific size).
[image]

*Here is the code...*

```
  Widget _build(BuildContext context) {
    var words = ["a", "abc", "de", "ef", "g", "i", "is", "s", "th"];

    return new Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Text('height 100'),
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 100.0,
          child: Wrap(
            alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: _buildWordButtons(words),
          ),
        ),
        Text('height 50'),
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: 50.0,
          child: Wrap(
            alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: _buildWordButtons(words),
          ),
        ),
        Text('FittedBox, scaleDown, height 200'),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: 200.0,
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
            child: Wrap(
              alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: _buildWordButtons(words),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildWordButtons(List<String> words) {
    var buttons = List<Widget>();

    for (var word in words) {
      buttons.add(Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
        child: Text(
          word,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      ));
    }

    return buttons;
  }
```

Comment: What is the desired render ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I auto scale down a font in a Text widget to fit the max number of lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665083/how-do-i-auto-scale-down-a-font-in-a-text-widget-to-fit-the-max-number-of-lines)

Comment: @RémiRousselet very good question! (I'm laughing and scratching my head at the same time!)  I think the behavious I need are...1. go to the maximum size as defined in the child (ie font:40), 2. if text is cut off wrap the text as much as is possible, 3. if the items are still cut off then shrink the individual widgets...shall I update with a screenshot?  Does that make sense?

Comment: I see. Somehow that is a relatively hard layout to do.

Comment: It doesn't have to be exactly like that, really just something that will expand a little when a screen is a bit bigger and shrink if there are too many items...if anyone has any other ideas...hardcoding the size for now :-)

Comment: @atreeon Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @Mahesh, no I didn't but if you do please share the solution

Comment: no solution yet ??

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to create a Text widget that will adapt to the size of its parent widget, you may want to look into [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) widget. Using this widget should help its child widget determine its parent widget's constraints. Since you've mentioned that having a spacious `Container` should print long texts in a newline, you can have it set inside the `LayoutBuilder`.

Here's a sample. I've modified the code snippet provided.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final words = ["a", "abc", "de", "ef", "g", "i", "is", "s", "th"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Text('height 100'),
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 100.0,
          child: adaptiveText(),
        ),
        Text('height 50'),
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: 50.0,
          child: adaptiveText(),
        ),
        Text('height 200'),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: 200.0,
          child: adaptiveText(),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }

  adaptiveText() {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        debugPrint('constraint maxHeight: ${constraints.maxHeight}');
        // adapt Text widget if parent widget size is <= 100
        if (constraints.maxHeight <= 100)
          return FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
            child: Wrap(
              alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: _buildWordButtons(words),
            ),
          );
        else
          return Wrap(
            alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: _buildWordButtons(words),
          );
      },
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildWordButtons(List<String> words) {
    var buttons = List<Widget>();

    for (var word in words) {
      buttons.add(Container(
        decoration:
            new BoxDecoration(border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
        child: Text(
          word,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),
          maxLines: 3,
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      ));
    }

    return buttons;
  }
}
```

Demo

[image]