# Flutter App Screen is appearing weird on Samsung S8

Tags: flutter, samsung

Image is here
[image: Screen on s8 and other phone Image]

Flutter app screen and text is appearing weird in Samsung S8 mobile
but tested in Other Samsung devises  and its working fine, you can see  how its supposed to work on the other devices on the above image

any one know why is this screen issue is happening only on samsung s8 ,only this image is here no log is getting so it is hard to resolve , is anyone faced this issue before,

minimumSdk is 21

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';
import 'package:splink/src/constants/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:splink/src/controllers/login_view_controllers.dart';
import 'package:splink/src/view/login_view/login_welcome_view.dart';
import 'package:splink/src/view/signup_view/signup_welcome_view.dart';

class LandingView extends StatefulWidget {
  const LandingView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LandingView> createState() => _LandingViewState();
}

class _LandingViewState extends State<LandingView> {
  final signLoginController = Get.find<LoginViewController>();
  final controller = PageController(
    viewportFraction: 1,
    keepPage: true,
  );

  List items = [
    "assets/images/6D2Lmtv_X8A.png",
    "assets/images/secondimage.png",
    "assets/images/thirdImage.png"
  ];

  List textItems = [
    //first page of intro
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        Text(
          "Find and play sports at",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 28, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        Text(
          "anywhere, anytime",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 28, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 25,
        ),
        Text(
          "splink helps you find, connect and organise activities",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "with other sports players easily at anywhere, anytime",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    //second page of intro
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        Text(
          "Organise and manage",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 28, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        Text(
          "activties easily",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 28, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 25,
        ),
        Text(
          "no more messy groups and missed activities.",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "Activity creation and RSVPs, calendar-tracking",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "or notifications, everything doe easily in-app",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    //third page of intro
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        Text(
          "Meet, play and endorse",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 28, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        Text(
          "one another",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 28, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 25,
        ),
        Text(
          "Have fun, encourage one another by exchanging medals,",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "track sports statistics and keep on playing!",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final pages = List.generate(
      3,
      (index) => Image.asset(
        items[index],
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
    final pages2 = List.generate(3, (index) => textItems[index]);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: primaryColor,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: ClipPathClass(),
              child: PageView.builder(
                controller: controller,
                padEnds: false,
                // itemCount: pages.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return SizedBox(
                      height: size.height,
                      width: size.width,
                      child: pages[index % pages.length]);
                },
                onPageChanged: (value) {
                  signLoginController.curouselIndex(value % pages.length);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: primaryColor,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: SmoothPageIndicator(
                      controller: controller,
                      count: 3,
                      effect: const ExpandingDotsEffect(
                        strokeWidth: 2.0,
                        dotColor: Colors.white,
                        activeDotColor: Colors.white,
                        dotHeight: 6,
                        dotWidth: 6,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Obx(
                    () => textItems[signLoginController.curouselIndex.value],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 70,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
                    child: Material(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Get.to(SignupWelcomeView());
                        },
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        child: Container(
                          width: size.width,
                          height: 50,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text(
                            'Sign Up',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 17,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                color: primaryColor),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Get.to(LoginWelcomeView());
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        width: size.width,
                        height: 50,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: const Text(
                          'Login',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ClipPathClass extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path.addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
      center: Offset(size.width * 0.5, -10),
      radius: size.height - 20,
    ));
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, the "issue" is that the width/pixel density of the device is causing the text to overflow to the next line. You can either use a `FittedBox`, or tweak the `fontSize` to optimize it depending on the width (using `MediaQuery` or `LayoutBuilder`), both sould work.

You can also align the text on the center, instead of to the right, and I'd add some padding to ensure the text doesn't go right up to the screen border.

[How do I auto scale down a font in a Text widget to fit the max number of lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665083/how-do-i-auto-scale-down-a-font-in-a-text-widget-to-fit-the-max-number-of-lines)

Comment: Thanks for your response , I have applied the FittedBox as per your suggession . i will test it in s8 and will tell you the the result